Cauchy-Schwarz in a complex Hilbert Space proof question
my instructor gave me the following proof for the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in a complex Hilbert Space, but I do not understand the following part:
With a fixed value of $|\lambda|$, the left side is maximal for $\lambda = -\gamma \overline{\langle x, y \rangle}$, where $\gamma > 0$. Why does $|\lambda|$ need to be fixed, and why does $\lambda = -\gamma \overline{\langle x, y \rangle}$, where $\gamma > 0$ maximize the left side, when I try to find the maximum value of the left side with regards to $\lambda$ i end up with a linear function which has no critical points.
Proof. We will consider the case of a complex Hilbert space. It is clear that when $x$ and $y$ are collinear, i.e., for $x = \alpha y$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, equality is achieved. Now, let us assume that $x$ and $y$ are not collinear, i.e., for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ we have $x + \lambda y \neq 0$. We need to prove that
$$|\langle x, y \rangle| < \|x\| \|y\|.$$
To obtain the desired inequality, we start from the positivity (for arbitrary $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$):
$$0 < \langle x + \lambda y, x + \lambda y \rangle = \langle x, x \rangle + \langle x, \lambda y \rangle + \langle \lambda y, x \rangle + \langle \lambda y, \lambda y \rangle = \|x\|^2 + \lambda \langle x, y \rangle + \overline{\lambda} \langle y, x \rangle + |\lambda|^2 \|y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + 2 \Re \{\lambda \langle x, y \rangle\} + |\lambda|^2 \|y\|^2.$$
Therefore, for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ it is fulfilled
$$-2 \Re \{\lambda \langle x, y \rangle\} < \|x\|^2 + |\lambda|^2 \|y\|^2.$$
With a fixed value of $|\lambda|$, the left side is maximal for $\lambda = -\gamma \overline{\langle x, y \rangle}$, where $\gamma > 0$. Then we obtain the inequality
$$-2 \Re \{(-\gamma \overline{\langle x, y \rangle}) \langle x, y \rangle\} < \|x\|^2 + |\gamma \overline{\langle x, y \rangle}|^2 \|y\|^2,$$
i.e.,
$$2 \gamma |\langle x, y \rangle|^2 < \|x\|^2 + \gamma^2 |\langle x, y \rangle|^2 \|y\|^2,$$
or equivalently
$$0 < |\langle x, y \rangle|^2 \|y\|^2 \gamma^2 - 2 |\langle x, y \rangle|^2 \gamma + \|x\|^2.$$
For $\langle x, y \rangle = 0$ the inequality (1.2) is fulfilled. For $\langle x, y \rangle \neq 0$ we obtain a quadratic inequality for $\gamma$, which is possible only for a negative discriminant, i.e., for
$$4 |\langle x, y \rangle|^4 - 4 |\langle x, y \rangle|^2 \|y\|^2 \|x\|^2 < 0,$$
equivalently for
$$|\langle x, y \rangle|^2 < \|y\|^2 \|x\|^2.$$
With this we have proven the inequality (1.2) and consequently the theorem.

If you don't fix $|\lambda|$ then there's no maximum, you can make it tend to $+\infty$, but that wouldn't be very useful to know.

At fixed modulus $|\lambda| = a$, you can write $\lambda = a e^{i\theta}$, $\langle x, y \rangle\ = b e^{i \theta'}$, $-2 \Re {\lambda \langle x, y \rangle} = -2ab \Re(e^{i \theta + \theta'})$ and search for the maximum in regard to $\theta$.

Thanks a lot, I think I understood the idea, not really to maximize the left hand but to fix $|\lambda|$ to be $|\lambda| = \gamma \overline{\langle x, y \rangle}$, where $\gamma > 0$. And the choices for $\lambda$ are either $-\gamma \overline{\langle x, y \rangle}$ or $\gamma \overline{\langle x, y \rangle}$ and from these choices we pick $-\gamma \overline{\langle x, y \rangle}$ because it  maximizes the left side out of these two. But again why do I need it to be the maximum?

The idea is that you want to extract as much information from your family of inequalities, so you get rid of "redundant" ones, aka you get rid of the $\lambda$s which provide less knowledge and only keep the $\lambda$s which give you inequalities where the difference between the LHS and RHS is the tightest you can get. Here it corresponds to maximising the LHS since the RHS wouldn't change.

Never mind, I used the representation that you gave me in your other comment and maximized it with regards to $\theta$ and everything clicked, thank you so much, I was stuck at that part for hours.

The part about the $\lambda$ needing to be fixed, and that expression maximizing the left hand side is not actually required for the proof. It is just a bit of extra information about the expression to give you an idea of where it comes from. But the proof could have just said "Now consider the case when $\lambda = -\gamma \overline{\langle x,y\rangle}$ for some $\gamma \in \Bbb R$", and proceeded. Everything said afterwards still follows.

Oh okay, and the reasoning for that I assume is because, in the final part where we look at the discriminant the $\gamma$ doesnt really matter since we have a polynomial of $\gamma$.
